# How to change service admin of Subscription programmatically

Tags: azure, powershell

I am looking for PowerShell commands or any API, so I can change the Service admin of my subscription. Going over a lot of documents but could not find any commands or API.

Manual Steps

1. Go to Subscription - Properties
2. Click Change Service Admin
3. Select the new ID and click OK

I want to automate the above steps.

thanks,
Div

Comment: Manual Steps in Azure portal
Go to Subscription - Properties
Click Change Service Admin
Select the new ID and click OK

Comment: Unfortunately, It cannot be done through Powershell. It can be done through EA portal if you have an Enterprise agrement.